# При изменении цвета itemView в Recycler, также меняются другие ItemView

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть ViewHolder, в котором я меняю цвет у ItemView по нажатию.
Но если после нажатия проскролить, то можно заменить, что также изменились ItemView через каждые 10 штук.
Почему так происходит?

```
inner class RecordListItemViewHolder(convertView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(convertView),
        LayoutContainer {
        override val containerView: View?
            get() = itemView

        fun bind(record : RecordItem, listener: (RecordItem) -> Unit){
            Log.d("Item Recycler", record.id.toString())
            if(record.isSelected){
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
                itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                itemView.tv_name.textSize = 16f
            }
            itemView.tv_name.text = record.name
            itemView.tv_duration.text = record.duration.millis.toStringTime()
            itemView.tv_date_created.text = record.createdDateTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener.invoke(record)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вьюхи элементов списка в RecyclerView переиспользуются. В итоге, когда вы скролите, следующие элементы списка не создаются с нуля, но берутся из списка ранее отрисованных.

Таким образом вам надо просто добавить логику закрашивания цветом для невыбранных элементов:

```
if (record.isSelected) {
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
    itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    itemView.tv_name.textSize = 16f
} else {
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
    itemView.tv_name.textSize = 14f
}
```